# Change default output path for VS2008 setup-project?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2008, windows-installer, setup-project

How do I change the default output path of a VS2008 setup-project?

It installs into Program Files\myOldProjectName right now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right-click on Setup Project --> View --> File System

Right-click on Application Directory --> Properties --> Default Location

Answer (score 1):

At "File System" window of setup project You can select "Application Folder" and set DefaultLocation property.

You can use installer properties ([listed here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa370905%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)). Just put property name in square brackets.